# Bounded first moment vs. bounded absolute moment?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds, means, law-of-large-numbers

I notice a couple different versions of the law of large numbers, one that assumes finite mean, another that assumes finite absolute first moment. Are these equivalent?

I think we can argue one direction by triangle inequality:
$|\mathbb{E}[X]|=|\int xdF(x)|\leq \int |x|dF(x)= \mathbb{E}[|X|]$,

but what about the converse?

Comment: According to basic Measure Theory  if $\int f d\mu$ exists and is a real number then $\int |f|d\mu <\infty$ because $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$ both have finite integral.